# how can i prevent d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw) from being used when i mousedrag on my nodes?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

As it is now, when i mousedrag on the background, it moves the whole graph. When i click and drag a node it also moves the whole graph. When i remove

```
d3.select(".graph")
  .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on('zoom', redraw));
```

I can click and drag the nodes just fine, but then i can't scroll or zoom in on the map. What i want is to be able to pan the map when i drag the background, and move the nodes when i click and drag the nodes.

Now when i tried to apply `.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on('zoom', redraw));` to a rect the movement was really shakey, so i kept it on .graph, but when i have it on graph, when i select the nodes, they move the whole thing. I tried a number of thing including `.call(d3.behavior.zoom().on('zoom', null));` on the `svg.selectAll("g")` I also tried to do some kind of conditional expression setting `enableevent` to false with `.on("mousedrag", function)` to no avail.
I just can't seem to find a way to make this work. You can get miserables.json from [here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045). Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

.node {
  stroke: #00000;
  stroke-width: 0px;
}

.link {
  stroke: #999;
  stroke-opacity: .6;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="graph"></div>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 1100,
    height = 900;

var color = d3.scale.category20();

var force = d3.layout.force()
    .gravity(.05)
    .charge(-700)
    .linkDistance(150)
    .size([width, height]);

var svg = d3.select(".graph").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append('g');

d3.select(".graph")
  .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on('zoom', redraw));

function redraw() {
  console.log("here", d3.event.translate, d3.event.scale);
  svg.attr("transform","translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")" + " scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")"); } 

d3.json("miserables.json", function(error, graph) {
  force
      .nodes(graph.nodes)
      .links(graph.links)
      .start();

  var link = svg.selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

  var node = svg.selectAll("g")
      .data(graph.nodes)
      .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class","node")
      .call(force.drag);

  node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.group * 20); })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
    .attr("pointer-events", "auto")
    .attr("class", "circlenode");

  node.append("text")
    .attr("text-anchor", "right") 
    .attr("fill","black")
    .style("pointer-events", "none")
    .attr("font-size", function(d) { 20 + 'px'; })
    .attr("font-weight", function(d) { return "bold"; })
    .text( function(d) { return d.name + ' (' + d.group + ')';});

  setTimeout(function() {
    node.classed("fixed", function(d) { return d.fixed = true; });
  }, 9000);

  force.on("tick", function() {
    link.attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
        .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
        .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
        .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    node.attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
        .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";});
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out. When i tried moving the background it didn't occur to me that i could use mouseover events to indicate when i was on the background.

First create a background.

```
svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "background")
    .attr("width", "100%")
    .attr("height", "100%")
    .attr("fill", "pink");
```

Then create mouseover events for the background and the places you want it to work and not work.

```
d3.select(".background")
.on("mouseover", function() {
  d3.select(".graphmap")
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw))
    .on("dblclick.zoom", null)
    .on("wheel.zoom", null);
})
.on("mouseout", function() {
  d3.select(".graphmap")
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", null))
    .on("dblclick.zoom", null)
    .on("wheel.zoom", null);
});
d3.select(".link")
.on("mouseover", function() {
  d3.select(".graphmap")
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", redraw))
    .on("dblclick.zoom", null)
    .on("wheel.zoom", null);
})
  .on("mouseout", function() {
  d3.select(".graphmap")
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().on("zoom", null))
    .on("dblclick.zoom", null)
    .on("wheel.zoom", null);
});
```

Now i just have to figure out how to make it not skip when it translates. :S

Comment: FWIW, I stumbled across a particularly feature-full example that does what you (and I) want, and more: http://bl.ocks.org/eyaler/10586116.  As its title suggests, it can Drag/Zoom/Pan/Center/Resize/Label/Filter/Highlight.